# Can't use dispatcher on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, dispatcher

I was looking around for refrences using dispatcher to call code on the UI thread and they say to do this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {OnSendSuccessful(); });
```

But I get a compiler error saying I cant access non-static method BeginInvoke in a static context. Any ideas? I tried to new up a dispatcher but that doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try using:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {OnSendSuccessful(); });
```

This uses a static method to get a dispatcher for use in a static context.