# wait until get completed (web service)

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, windows-phone-7

i am working on `web services`...
below is the method i have written to call a `web service`

```
 long UserID = CheckIfUserExist(temp);       
    if (UserID == -1)
           // WRONG RESULT <---
    else
          // RIGHT RESULT <---
```

the `CheckIfUserExist` method calling that web service and returning the output value (`UserID`)--->

```
public static long CheckIfUserExist()
{                
     long UserID = -1;
     client.GetAsync("me");  
     client.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
     {
         // some code
         if (Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result) == 0)
         {
               UserID = Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result);
         }
         return UserID;
     }
 }
```

but the `CheckIfUserExist` returning an output value befor exceuting the GetCompleted & its always going wrong result...

i also tried `manualResetEvent`, but its blocking my `UI Thread`... so not worked

so any one have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: look up `async` and `await`

Comment: can u explain (in brief) or gv me link ...

Comment: here's a [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=webservice+async+await) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[windows-phone-7]+async+webservice)

Comment: Note that you'll need Windows Phone 7.5 and this: https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ to get to use async and await

Comment: but i am using wp7, any other way to fix ths ?

Comment: Your code won't compile. It would help if you added your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I suggest you use the "await"-"async" technology . To make sure that the function is completly finished before continuing code .

Here is what your code should look like :

more info here -> 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

```
public async void updateUser()
{
   long UserID = await CheckIfUserExist(temp);       
   if (UserID == -1)
       // WRONG RESULT <---
   else
      // RIGHT RESULT <---
}
```

---

```
public async Task<long> CheckIfUserExist()
{                
     long UserID = -1;
     await client.GetAsync("me");  
     client.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
     {
         // some code
         if (Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result) == 0)
         {
               UserID = Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result);
         }
         return UserID;
     }
 }
```

Comment: was about to suggest await myself

Answer (score 3):

Async Await keywords are one way to solve your situation. However your actual problem is you dont understand how the `GetAsync` call works.
When you say:

```
public static long CheckIfUserExist()
{                
     long UserID = -1;
     client.GetAsync("me");  
     client.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
     {
         // some code
         if (Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result) == 0)
         {
               UserID = Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result);
         }
         return UserID;
     }
 }
```

It is equivalent to:

```
    public static long CheckIfUserExist()
    {                
     long UserID = -1;
     client.GetAsync("me");  
     client.GetCompleted += MyEventHandler;

    }

    void MyEventHandler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
    {
         // some code
         if (Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result) == 0)
         {
           UserID = Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result);
         }
         return UserID; // <-- WHAT IS POINT OF RETURNING UserID FROM HERE?? 
                        // method maybe running on some other thread asynchronously to UI thread
    }
```

There are two possibilities for you:
If your `client` object's `GetCompleted` event occurs on the UI thread you can do this:

```
 client.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
         {
             // some code
             if (Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result) == 0)
             {
               UserID = Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result);
             }
             // your logic here
             if (UserID == -1)
                  // WRONG RESULT <---
             else
                  // RIGHT RESULT <---
         }
```

If `GetCompleted` event does not occur on UI thread:

```
client.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
             {
                 // some code
                 if (Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result) == 0)
                 {
                   UserID = Convert.ToInt64(eargs.Result);
                 }
                 // let UI thread know we've got the result
                 Dispatcher.Invoke( (Action)(() => { NotifyUIThread(UserID) } ));
             }
...

void NotifyUIThread(long UserId) //This runs on UI thread
{
    if (UserID == -1)
       // WRONG RESULT <---
    else
       // RIGHT RESULT <---

}
```

Also, take care there you subscribe to event before you call `GetAsync`

```
client.GetCompleted += (o, e) => { ... } //subscribe first
client.GetAsync("me");  // call GetAsync later
```

If on WP7 - you may have problem with `Dispatcher.Invoke` see this: [Can't use dispatcher on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247729/cant-use-dispatcher-on-wp7)