# how to make asp.net application wait till web service send response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have a web application which sends some message to a web service. The web service then pass on the message to controller.This controller gets the large number of data and process it.
The problem is my web application gets time out while web service is still waiting and the controller is still processing. How to keep the web application alive untill it get the response from web service. I have already tried `<httpruntime>`. Please Help!!!

Comment: When you call the web service outside the web application, from a test application for example, do you get a response or a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Execution timeout and Session time out both are different things. Execution time for web application is 90 seconds, I think your web service take more time to execute the things, you need to increase the execution timeout in web.config as follows
Firstly, you need to increase the timeout of the executionTimeout attribute of the httpRuntime element.

```
<httpRuntime  executionTimeout="36000" ..

//to make above tag effective you need to make the compilation debug attribute set to false

<compilation debug="false" ../>
```

keep one thing in mind the execution time is always in seconds

Comment: still it gives timeout expired ? have you make compilation debug="false" ? can you show me your web.config

Comment: actually, after implementing this, my .net application waits for web service response... but now another issue i am facing is that the link between the .net application and web service is breaking down. so, the application keeps on waiting till time is out.. So, what could be the reason behind this???

Comment: Basically when you call webservice from your web application you need to show some WAIT message to user, so that you can wait for the webservice to complete the task and control will back to web application, go through following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230016/wait-until-get-completed-web-service  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600926/Asynchronous-web-services-call-in-ASP-NET